# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04LTS from 13.10 failed and now have a black screen

Tags: boot, upgrade, ext4

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04LTS. In between it asked about some configuration files whether to keep or replace them, for all I chose to replace them on each prompt but at the end installation said the machine is corrupted and cannot start.

NOTE: For kismet module while upgrading modules it gave an error popup.

I get the black screen with blinking cursor and also the below error screen.

ubuntu ext4-fs error (device dm-0): hdtree_dirblock_to_tree:920

When I hold SHIFT key while boot then I can choose an older kernel version and then I can login inside, I see the version show in About Ubuntu as 14.04LTS.

Please help on how can I fix the issue as my machine by default does not start and I get the black screen with blinking cursor.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: It's hard to advise without knowing what happend. Can you add the `/var/log/dist-upgrade` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This above answer helped me finish my upgrade.

While following instructions "Ubuntu Desktops 13.04 or 12.10 to 13.10 (Recommended)" here
    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades
and "Ubuntu Desktops 13.10 to 14.04 (Recommended)" here
    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades

I experienced the "black screen" after login at version 13.10.

I applied the fix, and proceeded to continue the upgrade to 14.04 when prompted.

When the upgrade was complete I was not seeing a black screen, but no controls were available and only the background and the "Ubuntu 14.04" logo was visible.

I rebooted to 3.13.0-27 (newest) recovery mode and selected "dpkg"

Now my system seems to be operating as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Run with an older kernel, open a terminal, and type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

this will reconfigure all your installed packages, and usually solves the problem!